# Add view controllers to array

Tags: iphone

How can i add these four view controllers to array

```
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]autorelease];    
ContainerViewController  *container= [[[ContainerViewController alloc]init]autorelease];
self.window.rootViewController = container;  
NSMutableArray *controllers = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i=0; i<23; i++)
{
    First *first = [[First alloc] init];
    Second *second = [[Second alloc] init];
    Third *third = [[Third alloc] init];
    Fourth *fourth = [[Fourth alloc] init];

    [controllers addObject:first];
    [controllers addObject:second];
    [controllers addObject:third];
    [controllers addObject:fourth];
    }

 [container setSubViewControllers:controllers];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

getting yellow warning that instance method setSubViewController not found return type defaults to id

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set this

```
- (void)setSubViewControllers:(NSArray *)subViewControllers;
```

in the .h of `ContainerViewController`  this will help you get rid of the warning but I am not sure what you are doing logically and also I would advice you to release your sub view controllers in the loop before allocating them again...

Answer (score 2):

To add the view controllers to the array, there's no need to have a for loop. Remove the loop, and add:

```
First *first = [[First alloc] init];
    Second *second = [[Second alloc] init];
    Third *third = [[Third alloc] init];
    Fourth *fourth = [[Fourth alloc] init];

    [controllers addObject:first];
    [controllers addObject:second];
    [controllers addObject:third];
    [controllers addObject:fourth];
```

For the view controllers in `container`: `setSubViewControllers` is not a valid method. However, you can add a child view controller with `addChildViewController`. You could loop through your array, and call [container addChildViewController:x#ViewController];
Something like:

```
for (id thisViewController in controllers) {
thisViewController = (UIViewController *)thisViewController;
[container addChildViewController:thisViewController];
}
```

Note: I haven't tested this code. Let me know if you have any problems.